# RN/ Firestore - How to use Firestore reference object to populate a nested array

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, foreach, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get an output like this using Firebase/Firestore

```
"topRecipes": [
{
  "id": "LGvuYa0pN2432fd",
  "created": 1531480386994,
  "prep": 25,
  "cook": 2
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "ingName": "golden caster sugar",
      "weight": 300,
    },
    {
      "ingName": "butter",
      "weight": 300,
    },
    {
      "ingName": "self-raising flour",
      "weight": 300,
    },
  ],
  "recipeName": "Butterfly cupcakes",
  "username": "John Doe",
  "uid": "c1Mi03C7KxOpKceazn8GLovGGW73",
},
]
```

I'm using Firestore reference object like a foreign key to populate the inner (ingredients) array however I feel what I've tried is extremely messy and it does not even work correctly.

```js
 constructor() {
      super() 
      this.state = { selectedIndex: 0, topRecipes: [] };
      this.recipesInit = [];
    }

componentWillMount() {
    let recipeList;
    db.collection("Recipes").orderBy("created", "asc").get().then((qss) => {
      
      qss.forEach((doc) => {
        
        const { created, prep, cook, recipeName, username, uid, flavorListRef } = doc.data();

        recipeList = {
          id: doc.id,
          created: created.Timestamp,
          prep: prep,
          cook: cook,
          recipeName: recipeName,
          username: username,
          uid: uid,
        }

        if (flavorListRef) {
          
          let combineRecipes = { ...recipeList, flavorList:[] };
          flavorListRef.collection("flavorList").get().then((sqss) => {

            sqss.forEach( docs => {
              
              const { ingName, weight } = docs.data();

              combineRecipes.flavorList.push({ 
                ingName: ingName, 
                weight: weight, 
              })
            }) //forEach
          })
          .then(() => {
            this.recipesInit.push( ...this.recipesInit, combineRecipes )
            this.setState({ topRecipes: this.recipesInit })
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }

      }) //forEach
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

The results currently produce the first result object twice followed by the rest of the results.

```
Object 0 {
  Array []
}
Object 0 {
  Array []
}
Object 1 {
  Array []
}
```

I want to know if there is a better method to get the data from Firestore and also how to manipulate this data to a json output correctly.

My db is currently setup 
/Recipes/asdkjaskda/flavorList/kjhasdkjhasd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all i had to do was

change this
this.recipesInit.push( ...this.recipesInit, combineRecipes )

to

this.recipesInit.push( combineRecipes )